# Radio buttons converting to images in Microsoft Word 2013 on save

Tags: html, ms-word, radio-button

I edited an existing word document using radio and text boxes. I added new radio buttons via the Legacy Tools\ActiveX Controls and copying the radio button off an unrevised document. However, even when I save the edited document as an .html document and reopen it all my radio and text boxes are now pictures.

Who do I prevent this from happening?

I made sure I have the latest updates, I've done Save-As and saved as Web Page (*.htm;*.html) and Web Page, Filtered (*.htm;*.html). I've tried just about anything I could find on the World Wide Web to no avail.  Please, through your suggestions at me on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Word's ActiveX controls aren't the same as controls that can be used in a web page. HTML doesn't know what to do with them, so they're saved as pictures. Word 2007, as I recall, had some "web tools" that could be used to create web pages, but Word is a poor HTML editor, so that was discontinued.

Comment: I found a solution that I will document below as my answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for this problem. Here are the steps I used to fix the problem:

1. Opened up old .htm forn in NotePad++
2. Opened up new .htm form in NotePad++
3. Found code radial button code in old .htm file
4. Copied code for the buttons
5. Found code in new .htm file
6. Deleted code for radial button in new .htm file
7. Pasted code from old .htm file into new .htm file
8. Made edits to button values, and repeated until done.

Here is a snippet of the code that I used to make it all work as expected.

```
<p><span lang=EN style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial Narrow",sans-serif;
mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#984806;mso-themecolor:accent6;
mso-themeshade:128;mso-ansi-language:EN'>New <span class=SpellE>RadialButtons</span>\Brand
folder</span><span lang=EN style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;
mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-ansi-language:EN'><span
style='mso-tab-count:1'> </span></span><span style='font-size:8.5pt;font-family:
"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'><INPUT TYPE="radio" CHECKED NAME="producttname1"></span><span
lang=EN style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:
"Times New Roman";mso-ansi-language:EN'>Button1</span><span style='font-size:8.5pt;
font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'><span
style='mso-spacerun:yes'>      </span><INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="producttname1"></span><span
lang=EN style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:
"Times New Roman";mso-ansi-language:EN'><span
style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span>Button2<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>   </span></span><span lang=EN
style='font-size:8.5pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333;
mso-ansi-language:EN'><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span></span><span
style='font-size:8.5pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'><INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="producttname1"></span><span
lang=EN style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:
"Times New Roman";mso-ansi-language:EN'><span
style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span>Button3:</span><span lang=EN style='font-size:8.5pt;
font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333;mso-ansi-language:EN'> </span><span
style='font-size:8.5pt;font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif;color:#333333'><INPUT TYPE="text"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Maybe the solution is not the preferred way, but for me it solved my problem, and I am happy with the solution along with my manager.